# Can't find certain .exe after starting up pc

Tags: windows, cmd, exe

Everytime I start up my laptop, I get the following error:

Can't find file C:\Users\robert\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\dhisevfi\eieteifb.exe Check if you have the entered the name correctly and try again after.

I can't find this .exe file anywhere on my laptop and even on the internet it can not be found. [Check here to see the image of the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKWKa.png)

StackOverflow is my last resort to solve this problem since no one seems to understand why it happens.

I would be very grateful if someone could me out a bit further.

Thanks in advance!

Robert

Answer (score 1):

I've just searched the internet and I didn't find the name of this executable, which most likely means that it has been generated automatically, which is a typical situation for ... a virus! (I had a similar situation several years ago)

So, apparently your computer has been infected with a virus, the corresponding executable is not (longer) present on your computer, but your computer (still) wants to launch it. (Don't worry: as the executable is not there anymore, there won't be any harm to your computer anymore)

I'd advise you to remove this entry from your startup folder, but this action depends on your Windows version. There are lots of entries about this subject all over the internet.

Comment: Thank you so much Dominique! I managed to find and delete the .exe from the startup folder by using shell:Startup. It works perfectly fine now, very grateful for your fast response!